# How to save an Excel fie with a new password in vba

Tags: vba

I'm trying to save a file with a new password, but when I reopen the file still asks me for the old password. The code I have is as follows:

```
    FileCopy strLastMonthFilePath, strFilePath
    
    ' Open MF
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFilePath, Password:=OldPassword, UpdateLinks:=0
    
    MF_FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Password:=NewPassword
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ' Close Source files
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Windows(MF_FileName).Activate
    Workbooks(MF_FileName).Close

    ' This line does not work. If if change it to the OldPassword then it works
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFilePath, Password:=NewPassword, UpdateLinks:=0
```

I tried also to assign the workbook and change the password to a variable but didn't work:

```
Set myWBk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFilePath, Password:=OldPassword , UpdateLinks:=0)
myWBk.SaveAs Password:=NewPassword
```

Any idea why the password does not change?

Comment: You are setting the new password to `ThisWorkbook` - that's the workbook where the code is stored, not the workbook that you just opened.

Comment: Uhm, I thought that when it is opened, ThisWorkbook refers to the one opened. I tried other options, assigning the workbook to a variable, but didn't work either. I'll amend the detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(1)** ThisWorkbook is always the workbook where the code is stored. Opening a workbook makes it the `ActiveWorkbook`. The `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has currently the focus. However, it is much better to store the workbook reference into a variable

**(2)** `SaveAs` creates a copy of the workbook. You need to use `Save` (or `Close` with parameter `True`). However, `Save` doesn't have a parameter to set or change the password, but this can easily be done using the `Password` property of the workbook.

Try this:

```
Dim myWBk  As Workbook
Set myWBk = Workbooks.Open(filename:=strFilePath, Password:=OldPassword, UpdateLinks:=0)
myWBk.Password = NewPassword
myWBk.Close True
```